# Groovy script for count value matches with offset

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

`<... count="6" offset="3,2,7,1,4,5"/>`

from the above snippet, i want to verify number of offset values should get match with count value. Please help to get SOAPUI REST services groovy script for this one.

Thanks!

Comment: As @Opal comment you've to provide more detail this way probably you can receive a better answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your question it's not clear so supposing that you've something like:

`<myTag count="6" offset="3,2,7,1,4,5"/>`

You can use `XmlSlurper` in groovy script to validate your requirement as follows:

```
def xmlStr = '<myTag count="6" offset="3,2,7,1,4,5"/>'
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlStr)

// use @ notation to acces attributes
def count = xml.@count
def offset = xml.@offset.toString().split(',')

// assert that count matches the length of the array
assert count == offset.length
```

Anyways consider to provide more details and what you tried as @Opal suggest in it's comment.

Hope it helps,